# Fullcalendar jump to date

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How can I make my custom button to make a jump to date function?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay, myCustomButton'
        },
        customButtons: {
        myCustomButton: {
            text: 'Jump to date!',
            click: function() {

                // Jump to date function
                alert('clicked the custom button!');
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide abit more context to what you are asking, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article about writing a great question.

Comment: by clicking on it. what is your actual question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes ADyson has answered this one for you but just to clarify; the example given in that answer will take you to the current date, you'll have to create your moment object with a static date if that's your intention, for example -

```
date = moment("2018-01-04", "YYYY-MM-DD");
$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date );
```

Or if you need to use the current date of the calendar as a basis to calculate your new date, say to go a week forward for example you could do the following -

```
currentDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
newDate = moment(currentDate).add(7, 'days').format();
$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', newDate );
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/ for more information on manipulating a moment.js object.

Comment: Additionally, you can switch the view to the same changed date using this code. `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');`

Answer (score 6):

This will make the calendar go to a specific day when clicked:

```
customButtons: {
  myCustomButton: {
    text: 'Jump to date',
    click: function() {
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', moment());
    }
  }
},
```

As shown, this will simply go to the current date (effectively the same as what the built-in "today" button" does). If you want it to do something different then you can potentially do something to allow the user to select a date. It's not clear from the question exactly what you want, beyond going to a (arbitrary) date, so it's hard to offer any more specific advice that this.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/ for details of the fullCalendar gotoDate method.

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/82/ for a working demo of the code above.